# Would using a grounded extension cord negate the effects of a ground prong missing from device?

Tags: wiring, grounding, extension-cord

Specifically:

I have a PA System with the ground wire missing.  It has shocked me in the past and I'd like to use it.  Short of a repair (which is coming), would using a grounded extension cord from the wall to the plug on the PA negate the shocking safety hazard that the ungrounded PA presents?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: No.  You need to cut off the damaged plug and put on a new one.  It's easy.   Meanwhile, welcome to Home Improvement.  You can take the tour at https://diy.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Comment: There is an option to purchase an extension cord with a ground fault circuit breaker (GFCI) built into it.  (These are quite common on construction job sites, etc, and are available at most building supply places.)  But replacing the device's plug or cord would be cheaper.

Answer (score 8):

### Nope!

Your problem is that you need to fix whatever is causing the shocks *and* replace the butchered plug.  There is no make-shift repair for this.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. I would cut the broken plug and get a replacement. Also make sure the PA is properly grounded inside as well.